# Statistic application: MongoDB vs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I have a SQL Server database that contains usage data of an application (from over 100 devices), with over 1 year of data collected (30GB database).

Inserting data into the DB is not a problem, is fast enough (for now), and is the only operation done by the clients.

There is one master table and a few child tables, but let's say I can put everything in a single table.

I need to do statistical analysis, so mostly `count(*)` filtering by date and by one or more columns. Performance is getting slow (done everything I could with indexes).

Would moving to MongoDB improve the speed? I haven't started to study it, but 99% of my operations would be (yes I know is not SQL):

```
select count(*) from table 
where date between date1 and date2 and field1 = 10 and field2 = "test"
```

Comment: Did you consider SQLServer analysis services? It sounds like you need quite a simple cube...

Comment: I doubt that MongoDB will help you with that. It isn't better for data analysis than SQL databases. It can, in fact, be even worse in some use-cases. What you need is a data analysis framework like Hadoop.

Comment: Did you investigate just tuning the SQL Server database instead of switching the product? You'll have to tune MongoDB as well!

Comment: I've been working on a project to migrate 38 million records from MySQl to MongoDB. Mongo can do reads & writes lightning fast at volumes which would lock a MySQL database. However, MongoDB is still subject to the same principals which cause bottlenecks on MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements can be easily handled by sql server.
 by the use of proper indexes and other optimization techniques.  these queries can be execute efficiently by SQL SERVER. for your use case a sinmple index on (date,field1,field2)

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TABLE_ID ON TABLE(id)
GO
CREATE  INDEX IDX_TABLE_2 ON TABLE(date,field1,field2)
GO
```

can be sufficient  for fast query execution.

**just a note:** 
For archival analysis SQL server Provides data warehousing tools(SQL SERVER ANALYSIS  SERVICE).
SQL SEREVER CUBE can aggregate and make analysis of huge archive data very simple.

for other sql server information : http://ms-sql-queries.blogspot.in/

Comment: Thanks but indexes are not a solution, that was just an example, I would have to make too many indexes, that would then slow down data insertion and take too much space.
I'll look for SSAS.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using any joins within the query then the performance of the sql server will not be affected. If you use mongodb for the same purpose then also the querying time will be about that of the sql one or a little worse.